# How to customize SVG Stroke Linecap

Tags: svg

I would like to know if anyone tried to create a custom shape on the SVG stroke-linecap. Instead of the standard (round, square), i would like to create a Inverse semicircle on the path in a countdown timer. Let me know if this is possible with SVG / if any one tried similar things.
Regards
Suresh

Comment: Attach a marker to the line via marker-end and marker-start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Robert suggested, you can use a `<marker>`, with `marker-end`, to add a custom end cap to a line.

```html
<svg>
  
  <defs>
    <marker id="InverseSemicircleEnd"
      viewBox="0 0 5 10" refX="0" refY="5" 
      markerUnits="strokeWidth"
      markerWidth="0.5" markerHeight="1"
      orient="auto">
      <path d="M 0 0 L 5 0 A 5 5 0 0 0 5 10 L 0 10 z" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  
  <line y1="75" x2="270" y2="75"
        fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="40"
        marker-end="url(#InverseSemicircleEnd)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: markers are very fiddly on IE - you might need to experiment

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention. IE has long-standing bugs with markers defined using `markerUnits="strokeWidth"`.  You can redefine your markers using fixed widths instead, but then you'll need to have one marker for each stroke-width you use.